# Spring environment specific properties

Tags: spring, spring-properties

I have a spring context configuration. Within this configuration i have following property-placeholder:

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:my_prop_file.properties,
    classpath:my_prop_file-${envTarget}.properties" ignore-resource-not-found="true"/>
```

The idea is, that all properties are set inside my_prop_file.properties and in the other property files i override only some (my_prop_file-env1.properties, my_prop_file-env2.properties etc).
This works fine. The problem is when I omit the vm argument -DenvTarget at startup. Is there a way to default it? When the value is not set, i receive:

```
Could not resolve placeholder 'envTarget' in string value
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create an empty my_prop_file-local.properties file and modify your property-placeholder definition to include a default value for envTarget.

```
<context:property-placeholder 
   location="classpath:my_prop_file.properties, classpath:my_prop_file-${envTarget:local}.properties" 
   ignore-resource-not-found="true"/>
```

Comment: Yes i tried the ${envTarget:local} before, but it was still failing for me. Just found out that i had a reference to this property in one more bean, where it was not defaulted and it caused the error described in the question. So yes the ${envTarget:local} works :)